# Angular 2 property binding

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have my component defined as follows:

```
export class WizardTabs {
@Input() Tabs: any;

@Input() selectedStepId: number=0;

selectedIndex: number = 0;
}
```

and template defined as follows:

```
<md-tabs md-border-bottom md-autoselect [selected]="selectedIndex">
<template md-tab *ngFor="let tab of Tabs" [label]="tab.Name" [selectedStepId]="tab.Id">
  <md-content class="md-padding">
    <wizard-tab-content [TabContent]="tab.StepComponent"></wizard-tab-content>
  </md-content>      
</template>
</md-tabs>
```

I want to access tab.Id inside my component. So I defined "selectedStepId" input property on component and binding it to tab.Id. However its throwing exception. I know we can bind properties from datasource to template but how to do it reverse i.e. bind property from template to component? In other words how to access variable defined in template from component?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can focus on getting Tab component instead of getting 'selectedStepId' property directly.
The decorator 'ViewChildren' may help you on this.

html file:

```
<md-tabs>
  <md-tab *ngFor="let tab of Tabs" [selectedStepId]="tab.Id"></md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

ts file:

```
class WizardTabs {

  @ViewChildren(MDTabComp) tabs:QueryList<MDTabComp>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.tabs.toArray().forEach((tab)=>console.log(tab.selectedStepId));
  }

}
```

Comment: @edmon-wang: Tabs property defined on WizardTabs is already populated. I need to figure out which tab (custom object) is associated with MdTabComp. Even if I get reference of whole tab object instead of tab.Id then also its fine.